# Weird gnome behaviour after reinstalling Ubuntu Gnome over a Unity installation

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome and I used as home a partition that had previously been used with Ubuntu unity from 15.04 to 16.10. While most things work fine, when I try to use a custom theme (by placing it in ~/.themes) with Tweak tools, the window controls are wrong and the general appearance seems off. It feels like there are some settings left over from unity, but I'm not sure about it. I've reinstalled gnome, gnome-shell, tweak tools. No change. How could I solve it?

Comment: You need to be more clear and explicit. "Fresh install" is a phrase usually used to describe installing an entire distro from an installation disk. Ubuntu-gnome is a specific metapackage. Tell exactly what you did.  Fresh install? apt-get -install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome? apt-get purge unity? What EXACTLY? In what order? I suspect you may be trying to run a theme for which you don't have all the prerequisites installed, but it's hard to guess when I don't know what you did.

Comment: Does this occur with all themes located in the .themes folder, or just one specific theme? It sounds like a theme problem.

Comment: @heynnema yes, any theme from the ~/.theme folder

Comment: The standard themes work fine, yes? Try and download a very **new** theme from gnome-look.org and see if that makes any difference. You may be using some old themes made for gnome 2 or older gnome 3 that may not be compatible. Report back.

Comment: I did and it actually work. It's weird since I had installed the same theme on a fresh install of Arch with Gnome a few days ago and everything was fine.... Regardless, thank you.